# AngularJS - How to use ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-controller

I want to show all the comments elements like a list by using the "ng-repeat" and "ng-controller" , but I don't know how to show the comments elements inside the dish !
like this :
5 stars
Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!
John Lemon,oct. 17,2012

4 stars
Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!
Paul McVites,Sep.06,2014
.
.
.

```
    var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

    app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {
      this.filtText= '';
      var dish=[
                  {
                    name:'Uthapizza',
                    image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                    category: 'mains',
                    lable:'Hot',
                    price:'4.99',
                    description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                     comments: [
                         {
                             rating:5,
                             comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                             author:"John Lemon",
                             date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                         },
                         {
                             rating:4,
                             comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                             author:"Paul McVites",
                             date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                         },
                         {
                             rating:3,
                             comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                             author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                             date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                         },
                         {
                             rating:4,
                             comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                             author:"Ringo Starry",
                             date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                         },
                         {
                             rating:2,
                             comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                             author:"25 Cent",
                             date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                         }

                     ]
              }];

      this.dish = dish;


    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Do you use the controller as `ng-controller="dishDetailController as <alias>"`? And show us the view too please

Comment: I don't know how to write the view !

Comment: I provided you a possible view in my answer

Comment: btw If you made a little more researches on Internet, you can easily find a solution. Little lazy dude

Comment: When I don't know something, I read [tutorials](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) first, then the the [API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api) so I don't have to beg for other developers to write the code for me!

Comment: Since "dish" is an array, I would suggest using the plural, "dishes". Also, the "comments" array is more than a comment. To me, I would call this array "reviews". Then, in your view, you can iterate through each dish in dishes and each review in dish.reviews to get the associated comment in the review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**

Since *dish* is an array, by convention, it should be pluralized, so I did it.

If you only want to iterate in comments of the first dish, it works:

```js
var app = angular.module('confusionApp', []);

app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {
  this.filtText = '';
  var dishes = [{
    name: 'Uthapizza',
    image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    lable: 'Hot',
    price: '4.99',
    description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
    comments: [{
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }
    ]
  }];

  this.dishes = dishes;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="dishDetailController as ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="c in ctrl.dishes[0].comments">
    <span ng-bind="c.rating + ' stars'"></span><br>
    <span ng-bind="c.comment"></span><br>
    <span>{{c.author}}, {{ c.date | date: 'MMM. dd,yyyy' }}</span><p>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

But you can also iterate in all dishes as the following, using [special repeats](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points):

```js
var app = angular.module('confusionApp', []);

app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {
  this.filtText = '';
  var dishes = [{
    name: 'Uthapizza',
    image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
    category: 'mains',
    lable: 'Hot',
    price: '4.99',
    description: 'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
    comments: [{
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        author: "Paul McVites",
        date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 3,
        comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
        author: "Michael Jaikishan",
        date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 4,
        comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        author: "Ringo Starry",
        date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }, {
        rating: 2,
        comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        author: "25 Cent",
        date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      }
    ]
  }];

  this.dishes = dishes;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="dishDetailController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat-start="d in ctrl.dishes" ng-bind="d.name"></div><br>
    <div style="margin-left: 10px" ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="c in d.comments">
      <span ng-bind="c.rating + ' stars'"></span><br>
      <span ng-bind="c.comment"></span><br>
      <span>{{c.author}}, {{ c.date | date: 'MMM. dd,yyyy' }}</span><p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For reference of filter used in date, you can check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: Thank you a lot , it works exactly with same result .

Comment: Is there any way to discard the black dots ?

Comment: If you mean the construction of `<ul> <li>` tags, yes, take a look at edited answer. Can you please accept the answer? (just click in the green button).

Comment: thank you again for helping , I found how to accept it .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple HTML that works only if your dish array contains 1 element. If it contains more than one element you can simply iterate through it

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="confusionApp">
<body>
    <div ng-controller="dishDetailController">
        <ul ng-repeat="c in dish[0].comments">
            <li>{{c.rating}} stars</li>
            <li>{{c.comment}}</li>
            <li>{{c.author}}, {{c.date | date: 'mediumDate' }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can change the `<ul>` tag by any other tag to fine-tune what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="comment in dish.comments | orderBy:query">
                <blockquote>
                    <p> {{comment.rating}} stars</p>
                    <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                    <footer>{{comment.author}} ,{{comment.date | date:'MMM,dd,yyyy'}}</footer>
                </blockquote>
            </li>
        </ul>
```